# Current measurment in energy meter

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, transformer

In AC circuits at the meter we have line and neutral going into the meter and then all devices are connected to it. For each and every device, we require a line and a neutral connection. If I want to measure current in a particular device so can I measure it in the following ways:

1. Introducing a current transformer in the line before the current is entering the device?
2. To measure current at the neutral end, i.e after load.

Is my last point correct or not?

Answer (score 3):

Your point 2 should be correct. [Kirchoff's Current Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchoff%27s_current_law#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29) says that the sum of all the currents going into a device has to equal the sum of all the currents flowing out of a device.

Therefore, if your load only has 2 wires connected to it (hot, neutral), then there should be equal current flowing through each wire.

There is a caveat, though: many devices also have a ground connection. Under normal circumstances, I believe most devices don't allow current to flow to the ground pin. However, sometimes it does happen. If that's the case, and you're measuring only the neutral wire, you may measure less current than is actually flowing into your load from the hot wire.